# Configure Dns Server in ubuntu Server

Tags: server

how to configure **Dns** in Ubuntu server , such as **reverse lookup zone** .

i need  the steps so Ubuntu Dns server will act like windows dns server .

Can anyone give me the instructions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the [Ubuntu Help page for DNS](http://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html) which has a step-by-step procedure for this.